# change in velocity if submarine

Tags: vector-analysis

A submarine is travelling at 20 km/h due east.  A short time later it is travelling due north at 15 km/h.  Calculate the change in velocity of the submarine.

My answer is 25km/hr at N53.13E

Comment: This is a bit unclear... What's the question you are asking?

Comment: calculate the change in velocity of the submarine. i think my ans is wrong

Comment: The change in velocity will be the difference of the later velocity vector minus the earlier velocity vector.  So this is $ \ (15 \ \hat{j}) \ - \ (20 \ \hat{i}) \ $ .  Your magnitude is correct, but consider that the eastward velocity must be completely canceled out, and a northward velocity must be added on.  This means that the **change** in velocity will be north and _west_.

Comment: why? isn't add 15j + 20i? instead 15j-20i?

Comment: Change of a physical quantity is defined as the later value minus the earlier value; this also applies to vector quantities.  The first velocity was $ \ 20 \ \hat{i} \ $ , and it changed to the later velocity of $ \ 15 \ \hat{j} \ $ .   You are being asked to find the vector that needs to be added to the first velocity to produce the second velocity.  Thus $$ 20 \ \hat{i} \ + \ (15 \ \hat{j} \ - \ 20 \ \hat{i} ) \ = \ 15 \ \hat{j} \ \ . $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take east as $\hat {i}$ and north as $\hat {j}$. So the final velocity is $15 \hat j$, initial velocity is $20 \hat i$. Hence change in velocity= $15 \hat j-20 \hat i$ whose modulus is 25, and direction is $36.87$ north-west. You can guess the direction by drawing a triangle of the vector addition. (add $15\hat j$ and $-20 \hat i$)

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: why is it -20? i don't get -20i

Comment: change in velocity is final velocity- initial velocity, right? So this gives you $15 \hat j-20 \hat i$